# check value exists in perl array and substring

Tags: arrays, excel, perl

I have an array with original data and a column in excel file, I need to compare the excel column with the array and find the match.

I need is walk should match with walk with me and so on, Is there any way I can do it.

```
can i compare individual string with complete array i am comparing excel row with array using the following way description variable contains string to match with @steps_name array

my @steps_name=("1-2 Steps", "5-7 Steps", "8-10 Steps", "11-15 Steps");

foreach $sheet (@{$workbook->{Worksheet}}) {

       foreach $col ($sheet->{MinCol} .. $sheet->{MaxCol})
       {          
                if ($sheet->{Cells}[0][$col]->{Val} eq "DESCRIPTION") 
               {
                    $description = $col;                    
               }                 
       }



    foreach $row ($sheet->{MinRow}+1 .. 50) 
     {         
       my $db_description = $sheet->{Cells}[$row][$description]->{Val};

        my $needle_regex = quotemeta $db_description;    

     if (grep { /(?i)\Q$db_description\E/ } @steps_name) 
                {
           print "<br><h1>Element '$db_description' found </h1></br>" ;
                }

                else
                {
                    print "<br>$db_description not found </br>"
                }

      }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you already know how to read the Excel file?

Comment: yes i know i am doing it by using  foreach $row ($sheet->{MinRow}+1 .. 10) 
    {}

Comment: You should include some more information about what you do with the file, and what the file looks like. This is way too vague.

Comment: my basic requirement is to match the 2 strings above .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning a list to a scalar (`$db_description`) doesn't make any sense. Also, `eq` tests for string equality, and none of the strings you're comparing will ever be equal. You probably want to use a regular expression to see if your *needles* match part of your *haystacks*:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @needles   = ("walk", "run", "dance", "catch");
my @haystacks = ("walk with me", "come and run", "catch the ball");

for my $needle (@needles) {
    my $found;

    for my $haystack (@haystacks) {
        if ($haystack =~ /\Q$needle\E/) {
            print "Found [$needle] in [$haystack]\n";
            $found++;
        }
    }

    if (!$found) {
        print "Couldn't find [$needle] anywhere!\n";
    }
}
```

This could be shortened to:

```
for my $needle (@needles) {
    if (grep { /\Q$needle\E/ } @haystacks) {
        print "Found [$needle]\n";
    } else {
        print "Couldn't find [$needle] anywhere!\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: this is working but it is case sensitive, can it be done without it.Thanks for the solution .

Comment: @rohan perhaps you want to use the `/i` regex flag for case-insensitive matches?

Comment: $haystack =~ /\i\Q$needle\E\i/ used this way but not working.

Comment: @rohan are you just guessing at the syntax? Check out [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and it should become clear what needs to be done.

Comment: still not working .. my string contains numbers also is that a problem .

Comment: @rohan "still not working" doesn't tell me very much. I'd have to see the actual code.

Comment: my  needles   = ("1-2 Steps ", "5-7 Steps", "8-10 Steps", "catch");
my haystacks = (" 1-2 Steps", "move 8-10 steps to hoist", "catch the ball");

for my $needle (@needles) {
    my $found;

    for my $haystack (@haystacks) {
        if ($haystack =~ /\i\Q$needle\E\i/) {
   print "<br>";
            print "Found [$needle] in [$haystack]\n";
   print "</br>";
            $found++;
        }
    }

    if (!$found) {
  print "<br>";
        print "Couldn't find [$needle] anywhere!\n";
  print "<br>";
    }
}

Comment: @rohan Your application of `/i` is the same as it was a few comments ago. Did you read the perlre manual page I linked to?

Comment: I believe your RegEx should look like `$haystack =~ /\Q$needle\E/i`