# compare string with array to find a match

Tags: regex, perl

can I compare individual string with complete array. In the below case i am not able to satisfy the condition may be due to improper regex due to case sensitive, I want to match any word.

eg. MOVE 1-2 STEPS should match 1-2 Steps,MOVE 8-10 STEPS should match 8-10 Steps so on .

```
my @db_description=("MOVE 1-2 STEPS TO GB FIXTURE","WITHIN REACH TO CHECK","GET BEAM","PUSH/PULL ( >= 30 CM)","BEAM 2-3 TIMES","MOVE 8-10 STEPS TO HOIST");
my @steps_name = ("1-2 Steps", "5-7 Steps", "8-10 Steps", "11-15 Steps");

    for(my $i=0;$i<@db_description;$i++)
    {
                if (grep { /(?i)\Q$db_description[$i]\E/ } @steps_name) 
                    {
                         print "<br><h1>Element '$db_description' found !</h1></br>" ;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                         print "<br>$db_description not found </br>"
                    }
    }
```

Comment: yes its pseudo code, and not the actual i am basically looking for the condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check value exists in perl array and substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259793/check-value-exists-in-perl-array-and-substring)

Answer (score 0):

You have written some awful Perl, and I am unsure of what you meant. Can you explain better?

It looks like you want to parse a bespoke language, so simple grabs of substrings aren't going to work

Is this homework, based on a machine that has been specified to you? Or are you working for a living doing this? If the latter then you have withheld information from us, so we can't help you very well.

The obvious problem is that your C-style `for` loop would be better as a range, but you never use `$i` within the loop block

Here's a version of your code that I tidied manually. I hope it helps someone else to help you

```
my @db_description = (
    "MOVE 1-2 STEPS TO GB FIXTURE",
    "WITHIN REACH TO CHECK",
    "GET BEAM",
    "PUSH/PULL ( >= 30 CM)",
    "BEAM 2-3 TIMES",
    "MOVE 8-10 STEPS TO HOIST",
);

my @steps_name = (
    "1-2 Steps",
    "5-7 Steps",
    "8-10 Steps",
    "11-15 Steps",
);

for ( my $i = 0; $i < @db_description; $i++ ) {

    if ( grep { /(?i)\Q$db_description[$i]\E/ } @steps_name ) {
        print "<br><h1>Element '$db_description' found !</h1></br>";
    }
    else {
        print "<br>$db_description not found </br>";
    }
}
```

An aside: please never use `(?i)` unless you especially need it. For instance, to build a regex pattern that will be used as a part of other patterns while the restriction should apply only for the subpattern.

Comment: your solution doesn't help,but thanks for the formatting.

Comment: @rohan: I'm not surprised it doesn't help. No one can  fathom your question, and your code doesn't make much sense. I said as much as I could given what you wrote, and your reaction should be to fix your question and explain yourself better, not to give up and walk away. Your question has three down votes and two close votes, so it's not just me that thinks so.

Answer (score -1):

His question is valid.. Try following code

```
my @db_description=("MOVE 1-2 STEPS TO GB FIXTURE","WITHIN REACH TO CHECK","GET BEAM","PUSH/PULL ( >= 30 CM)","BEAM 2-3 TIMES","MOVE 8-10 STEPS TO HOIST");
my @steps_name = ("1-2 Steps", "5-7 Steps", "8-10 Steps", "11-15 Steps");
my $testString1;
my $testString2;

my @abc;
my @xyz;

for(my $i=0;$i<$#db_description;$i++)
    {
    @abc = split (/ /,$db_description[$i]);
    for(my $j=0;$j<$#steps_name;$j++)
     {
         @xyz = split (/ /, $steps_name[$j]);
         for (my $i1=0; $i1<$#abc; $i1++)
            {
            for (my $j1=0; $j1<$#xyz; $j1++)
            {
                if ($abc[$i1] eq $xyz[$j1])
                {
                 print "$db_description[$i]  :: found $abc[$i1] == $xyz[$j1]\n";
                 }
             }

         }
     }
    }
```

Comment: you can also use if exist in perl